# Подключение библиотеки WiringPi в Qt на миниПК на Ubuntu Mate

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qtcreator, gpio

Имеется одноплатный компьютер Odroid XU4 с операционной системой Ubuntu Mate. Необходимо просто "подрыгать" ножками GPIO. Пример с офф. сайта (https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/application_note/gpio/wiringpi) работает прекрасно, но нужно, для дальнейшей разработки, перенести проект в Qt Creator. Вот здесь и возникает сложность. При компиляции возникают ошибки типа:

```
 'wiringPiSetup' was not declared in this scope
 'pinMode' was not declared in this scope
 'digitalWrite' was not declared in this scope
```

Ниже приведены .pro файл и часть mainwindow.cpp файла.

.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mine
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
CONFIG +=c++11
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lwiringPi
```

часть mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
    ...
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(27, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(27, HIGH);
    ...
```

Правильность установки WiringPi на компьютер проверил командной

```
gpio readall
```

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86674/discussion-on-question-by-nowsan---wiringpi--qt--).

Answer (score 3):

Как было выяснено благодаря обсуждению в комментариях, файл "wiringPi.h", в версии для Odroid (в отличии "родной" версии для RPi), не содержит прототипы используемых функций, поэтому необходимо просто прописать эти прототипы самому после подключения .h файла.

```
extern "C"{
    extern          void wiringPiSetup  (void);
    extern          void pinMode        (int pin, int mode);
    extern          void digitalWrite   (int pin, int value);
}
```